# I cannot define my fasta file, which I output in R, with the "makeblast" command in the terminal

Tags: r, terminal, fasta, blast

I got fasta output by using the following codes in R. And I need to read my fasta file (homo_ref.faa) that I obtained using these codes as "`makeblastdb -in homo_ref.faa -dbtype prot`" via terminal. But I get "`BLAST options error: File homo_ref.faa does not exist`". How would you recommend me to make changes to my code for this?

```
library(seqinr)
library(Biostrings)
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)



#read homo_tabular format
homo_tab = read.csv("proteins_homo.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")

homo_tab_1 = homo_tab[,c(7,9:11)]
colnames(homo_tab_1)[2]="ID"


#select longest locus
 son <- homo_tab_1 %>%
  group_by(Locus) %>%
  slice_max(Length, n = 1) %>%
  slice_head(n = 1)


 #read homo protein fasta ile and convert list to df/dt
human_prot <- read.fasta(file= "homo_s.faa", seqtype="AA", as.string =TRUE, set.attributes =TRUE)

human_prot = unlist(human_prot)
human_prot = as.data.frame(human_prot)
human_prot = setDT(human_prot, keep.rownames = "ID")
#rename column
colnames(human_prot)[1] ="ID" 
colnames(human_prot)[2] ="seq"

#merge csv and fasta file
merged = merge(human_prot , son , by="ID", all.x=TRUE)

#remove na rows
library(dplyr)

merged_1 <- na.omit(merged)

#delete column
merged_2 = subset(merged_1, select = -c(3,4,5) )



write.fasta(sequences = merged_2, names = names(merged_3), file.out = "homo_ref.faa")
```

[where i get tabular and fasta file:](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genome/?term=homo%20sapiens)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried typing the path to the fasta file? For example  `makeblastdb -in /Usr/Desktop/homo_ref.faa -dbtype prot`

Comment: Yes I tried but it didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with following this code: "`chmod a+r homo_ref.faa`". Thanks to the Mensur Dlakic similar question answer.